# getting negative byte array length or large amount of byte array length at client side in java

Tags: java, sockets

I am transmitting image from server to client. Server capture the screen and convert it to byte array and client receive byte array and convert back it to image. but transmission happens only for few frame and then error occurred.

Receiver side:

```
while(true) {
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(csocket.getInputStream());
    int len = dis.readInt();
    System.out.println(len);
    byte data[] = null;
    data = new byte[len];
    dis.read(data);
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    BufferedImage image1=ImageIO.read(in);
    ImageIcon imageIcon= new ImageIcon(image1);
    Image image = imageIcon.getImage();
    image = image.getScaledInstance(cPanel.getWidth(),cPanel.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_FAST);
    //Draw the recieved screenshot
    Graphics graphics = cPanel.getGraphics();
    graphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, cPanel.getWidth(),cPanel.getHeight(),cPanel);
}
```

Sender Side:

```
while(continueLoop) {
    try {
        BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
        byte[] imageInByte;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image,"jpg", baos);
        baos.flush();
        imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
        baos.close();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        //PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

        //out.flush();
        dos.writeInt(imageInByte.length);
        System.out.println(imageInByte.length);
        dos.write(imageInByte);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        dos.flush();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Output of Receiver:

```
 1177222283
 -297418067
 1228900861
 -412483840
 189486847
 10536391
 -33405441
 12898815
 740182
 -16736067
 -805436987 
 -16726825
 258150991
 2137853087
 1917408603
 512024791 
 -1227886373
 -1034512766
 1772271848
 157387
 Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:228)
 at remoteclient.ClientScreenReciever.run(ClientScreenReciever.java:65)
```

Please help me..what to do for continuous transmission of image from server to client over socket in faster way in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using

```
DataInputStream#read(byte[])
```

which (check its Javadoc) does not guarantee that a full arrays-worth of data will be read. This method is used for *buffered reading* and not to fully read the requested amount of bytes.

Instead you must call

```
DataInputStream#readFully(byte[])
```

which has a contract suiting your purpose (again check the Javadoc).